# Science behind mutual inductance dot convention

Tags: inductor

I have gone through several links about the dot convention of mutual inductance, but nowhere could I find the reason why a dot is placed where it's placed. Is it to do with any direction of current and field or some other reason I cannot understand? Can anyone elaborate on the physics behind the dot position?

Comment: You mean how current flows into the dotted end and out the other dotted end on a transformer?

Comment: Yes. I think that would explain my question as well. Another way of asking this would be, if i am a manufacturer who makes inductor and lets say i wound a wire into a coil. On what basis will i place the dot?

Comment: It's a *convention*.  The why of it is a question for historians.  As far as a physical meaning, if you wind two wires together on a core, then the spot where two wires exit the core together get the dot for both wires.

Comment: The word **convention** inherently means that there is no rationale but something people have agreed upon.

Comment: @TimWescott if you wind two wires together won't they exit the core together on both ends?

Comment: Yes.  So pick one end at random, and assign a pair of dots there.

Comment: Another way to view Tim's comment is this: the adjacent ends of the 2 wires will have the same polarity. Thus if one end of one wire is driven positive, the adjacent wire (disconnected from the other wire) will also, thru the energy coupling of magnetic fields, be moving positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand this from the [Transformer page on Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/transf.html).

To summarize, the direction of the magnetic field through the core depends on the direction the primary wire is wound around the core.

Similarly, the direction of the secondary EMF depends on the direction of the magnetic field and the direction of the secondary wire is wound around the core.

In this image (from Hyperphysics), the dots would both be placed on the upper side (or both on the lower side) of the coils, but be careful to notice the direction of the windings:

[image]

This analysis is derived from [Faraday's Law of induction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html#c1)